# xkb - Keymaps at `/usr/share/X11/kbd/symbols` 2 values vs 4 values being specified

Tags: x11, xkb

I was checking the keymap found at `/usr/share/x11/kbd/symbols` and in particular, I was browsing the `us` keymap and I didn't understand how this works:

> key `<TLDE>` { [dead_grave, dead_tilde, grave, asciitilde ] };

I understood that:

> key `<TLDE>` { [ grave, asciitilde ] };

meant that for regular keypress of <kbd>`</kbd>, I would get `grave` on the screen and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> would result in `asciitilde (~)`.

So, how can 4 values be represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two values are for `ISO_Level3_Shift` and `ISO_Level3_Shift+Shift` (`ISO_Level3_Shift` generally corresponds to the AltGr key).